# Magento 1.7.0.2 cart gets empty when canceling payment on PayPal page

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.7

I found some hacks how to fix this, but all of them are for lower versions.
Its hard to believe that magento did not patch this up, but hey you never know.

So if someone knows a working hack to keep the items in card when pressing "Cancel and return to XXXXX" on PayPal I would me most grateful.

Im using PayPal Website Payment Standard and Magento 1.7.0.2.

Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is, the order is finished for magento with the redirect to paypal. The cart is not emptied because of the cancel. It is emptied on the redirect page.

it happens here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php:240
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Is there a possible solution for this?

Comment: what is your expected behaviour? That after canceling the payment on the paypal site, the cart is restored? You have to check wether you know the quite_id when the customer comes back, if you don't know it, save it to a cookie. then restore it. but be careful it is not planned to do that. there is a column `converted_at` and I don't know what will happen if you resuse a converted quote. You might clone it and unset the ids. Good luck! :)

Comment: sure that is the expected behavor isnt it? Well it sounds complicated and im surprised that I am the only one that consider this as "expected behavor"

Comment: in germany the contract is concluded, when the customer clicks on buy after the review. this is the point for magento too to close the order. therefor I see no reason to do it in another way. I understand your problem. But I have at the moment no idea how to handle it in another way. You can avoid to convert the quote into an order and to it later, but when?